# Adding rows based on condition - Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below:

[image]

I want to add a new row based on the following logic:

1. Add a new row with "location" as "Stage Area"
2. This row is a sum of the entries where 'location' is "Reply's Area - New Commercial Area"
   and entries where 'location' is "Cultural Hub".
3. Drop the rows with
   'location' as "Reply's Area - New Commercial Area" and "Cultural
   Hub"

So for 11th November 2020 I should have the below entry:

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for filter by multiple values, aggregate sum add column `location` and last add to original DataFrame without matched rows by mask:

```
mask = df['location'].isin(["Reply's Area - New Commercial Area", 'Cultural Hub'])

df1 = (df[mask].groupby(['day','locationTypes'],as_index=False)[['dwell', 'football']]
              .sum()
              .assign(location = 'Stage Area')
              .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))

df = pd.concat([df[~mask], df1], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Jezrael looks like he was close with the answer, but maybe the aggregation on football won't be correct... just from looking at his code, so I might be wrong.

The correct version would look like this, and this matching the figures you suggested in your example.
I made a smaller version of your example table for testing. Here "data" is your dataframe.

```
mask = data["location"].isin(["Repley's Area - New Commercial Area", "Cultural Hub"])
data[mask].groupby(["day","locationTypes"], as_index=False)['dwell', 'football'].sum().assign(location="Stage Area")
```

The output:

```
          day locationTypes  dwell  football    location
0  2020-11-11          Zone    145      2307  Stage Area
1  2020-11-12          Zone     95      2905  Stage Area
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses! The following worked:

```
mask=df[df['location'].isin(["Repley's Area - New Commercial Area",'Cultural Hub'])]

df1=mask.groupby(['day','locationTypes'],as_index=False)['footfall','dwell (minutes)'].sum().assign(location='Stage Area')

#reordering the columns for pd.concat
df1= df1[df.columns]

df_final=pd.concat([df[~df['location'].isin(["Repley's Area - New Commercial Area",'Cultural Hub'])],df1]) 

#checking the result
df_final[(df_final['day']=='2020-11-11') & (df_final['location']=='Stage Area')]
```

#which gives

[image]

Comment: Oki, added `reindex` for change order of column